# Clerk auth Unregistered user tries to sign-in getting error

Tags: next.js, react-server-components, clerk

When an unregistered trying to sign-in instead of sign-up, clerk is redirecting to this url

http://localhost:3000/sign-in#/sso-callback?after_sign_up_url=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fonboarding&after_sign_in_url=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fdashboard

is there way configure this behaviour so it should redirect to sign_up

im using middleware to handle auth routing

```
export default authMiddleware({
    publicRoutes: ['/'],
    afterAuth(auth, req, evt) {
        // Handle users who aren't authenticated
        if (!auth.userId && !auth.isPublicRoute) {
            return redirectToSignIn({ returnBackUrl: req.url });
        }
        
        if (auth.userId && auth.isPublicRoute) {
            return redirect("/dashboard");
        }
    },
});
 
export const config = {
  matcher: ["/((?!.+\\.[\\w]+$|_next).*)", "/", "/(api|trpc)(.*)"],
};
```

Im using clerk to manage auth and it is having issue with unregistered users trying to sign-in instead of sign-up, which seems like a routing issue

Answer (score 0):

I work at Clerk as a DevX Engineer :)
So this is currently behaving as expected you have a manual redirect to sign-in in your `afterAuth` when the `userId` isn't present (not signed in) & the route is not public, this snippet:

```
  if (!auth.userId && !auth.isPublicRoute) {
        return redirectToSignIn({ returnBackUrl: req.url });
    }
```

I would suggest changing this to control components with given buttons instead, since the system cannot know if a person is already signed up until they actually sign-in, however, the User does know this and you can utilize the Clerk control flow components with "UnstyledButtons" example:

```
  <SignedIn>
    <SignOutButton />
  </SignedIn>
  <SignedOut>
    <SignInButton />
    <SignUpButton />
  </SignedOut>
```

This would handle the authentication/authorization flow at the component level with User input rather than trying to infer if they are signed-up which is not easily doable at the Middleware level especially without input information from the User.